# how to display the breadcrumbs from right to left in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

i am very rookie in Yii2 and i have recently ran into a problem about breadcrumbs in Yii2, i don't know how to change the direction of the breadcrumbs, by default the breadcrumbs in yii2 is from left to right i suppose but i want display it from right to left.
this is the breadcrumbs in my layout:

```
  <?=
Breadcrumbs::widget([
    'homeLink' => ['label' => 'Home',
    'url' => Yii::$app->getHomeUrl() . 'index.php?r=main/index'],
    'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [], 
]);
?>
```

and the breadcrumbs i have used in other views resembles the following:

```
<?php
$this->title = 'Update Product: ' . $model->title;
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Product', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => $model->title, 'url' => ['view', 'id' => $model->id]];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = 'Update';
```

?>

Answer (score 2):

You can extend `yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs`, change the way links are rendered and use it instead of original widget. Something like:

```
<?php

namespace your\namespace\for\widget;

use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs as OriginalBreadcrumbs;

class Breadcrumbs extends OriginalBreadcrumbs
{
    public function run()
    {
        if (empty($this->links)) {
            return;
        }
        $links = [];
        if ($this->homeLink === null) {
            $links[] = $this->renderItem([
                'label' => Yii::t('yii', 'Home'),
                'url' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
            ], $this->itemTemplate);
        } elseif ($this->homeLink !== false) {
            $links[] = $this->renderItem($this->homeLink, $this->itemTemplate);
        }
        foreach ($this->links as $link) {
            if (!is_array($link)) {
                $link = ['label' => $link];
            }
            $links[] = $this->renderItem($link, isset($link['url']) ? $this->itemTemplate : $this->activeItemTemplate);
        }
        // only difference here - array_reverse
        echo Html::tag($this->tag, implode('', array_reverse($links)), $this->options);
    }
}
```